# Determine equation of a line given a point and a number of degrees

Tags: trigonometry

If we are given a point 3,6 and a degree of 45, how can we find another point on this line? Obviously in this case we know that another point is 4,7, but how can we determine this if we are given any other number of degrees, like 256?

Comment: Do you know sines and cosines?

Comment: This has something to do with unit circles and trigonometry. Additionally, don't assume that $0$ degrees is north. Most of the time, $0$ is east, $90$ is north, $180$ is west ...(once again see unit circle).

Comment: @Skupp I removed that assumption. I can just adjust for that later.

Comment: @RossMillikan Having no experience with trigonometry, I am not sure if I do. I know its x and y, and the direction it is facing as a number of degrees. For any other details I would need a little guidance, which is what I am here for.

Comment: @jdgregson Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let: $P_0(x_0,y_0)$ the given point and $\alpha$ the angle, thus:

> $$P(x,y):y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$ with $$m=tan(\alpha)$$

Comment: Please forgive me, but I am having a bit of difficulty understanding this notation. Where are `x` and `y` coming from if `x0` and `y0` are the given points? For `m(x−x0)` am I multiplying the result of `tan(α)` with `(x−x0)`? I would really appreciate it if you could talk me through this using 2,3 as the known point 34 as the angle.

Comment: @jdgregson $A(2,3)$ is the known point and $\alpha=34°$ is the angle. The equation of the line passing through $A$ and forming an angle $\alpha$ with positive $x$ direction is $$y-3=\tan 34°(x-2)$$. Hope this can be useful...